# JDBC connection refused: postgres / same machine

Tags: java, windows, postgresql, jdbc

I know my message can seem a duplicate of another, but I don't think so. Tell me if I'm wrong.

I just finished a free software in Java/swing/postgresql. It was successfully tested on Windows and Linux.

Now I am trying to make the documentation of it, and I'm on the "Installing postgresql server" part of the documentation.

The problem is that I can't remember what I've done to make the application work with PostgreSQL (I know it's lame...).

The JDBC string is made this way in the code:

```
// Open the SQL Connection 
m_sql_connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://"+m_postgresql_server_name+":"+m_postgresql_port_number+"/"+m_postgresql_database_name, "postgres", "<not empty>");
```

The facts:

- I work on a Windows 7 machine 64 bit
- The PostgreSQL server is running (I see the service Started)
- The PostgreSQL server configuration seems OK
- I use login: postgres / pass: in my JDBC string
- I can make the queries I want with pgAdmin III and they work
- The database server is on the same machine as the "*.jar" application file
- The jar application works well on a Linux version and another Windows 7 32 bit machine (the development machine)
- I disabled my antivirus (just in case...)
- psql.exe works well (I could insert data with it)

**Edit 1 -> JJF**
 - I just added **postgresql.exe** and **pg_ctl.exe** in the windows firewall, and checked Both checkboxes for each (**Public** and **Home/Work(Private)** )

Result: Same Error

**Edit2 -> Hardik Patel**
 - Skype is already OFF

**Edit 3 -> JJF**
 - After full stop of Windows Firewall, still the same problem

The error I get is this one:

```
Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections
```

I wonder if I don't have to "unlock" the **postgres** account to allow it to access data through JDBC.

**Edit 4 - Horse with no name**
 - I replaced localhost by 127.0.0.1
 - The port is the standard port 5432, validated with psql
 - I tested the psql.exe (working) command line before trying the JDBC connection (not working)
 - Still the same result...

**Edit 5**
 - I am going to put some trace to see if i can get more information

Comment: Please show the connection string that's produced by your code, not just the code. If it's a dns name, resolve the dns name and make sure it matches what you expect it to resolve to.

Comment: The error can mean one of the following: 1. Postgres isn't running, 2. Postgres is listening on a different port, 3. The hostname you specified does not resolve properly (try `127.0.0.1` instead to verify that point)

Answer (score 0):

Turn off skype if running because skype acquires same port. This trick helped me long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Windows firewall is not blocking the port.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected my problem by a **workaround**.
I changed the PostgreSQL listen port by 5433 and everything worked like a charm...

I think the original port is used by something else, or blocked by some security tool I could not find.